# calculation of GIR in golf statistics

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo31Y.jpg)am hoping someone can help create a formula for the following scenario in my golf stats
I want cell c5 to be 0 or 1 for the following: 
c1 is the par of the hole which is 4
c2 is my score for the hole which is 5
c3 is the number of putts for the hole which was 2

In c5 I wish to calculate the strokes I took from c2 (5) and subtract the number of putts from c3 (2). This would then become the no. of strokes I took to reach the green (GIR) (called green in regulation) and if this figure is 3 or anything less than 3 and the par is (4) in c1 AND I receive a shot on this hole according to my handicap, then c5 would show 1. Any value more than 4 in c5 would mean that I did not reached green in regulation then would show as 0.

Does a excel formula exist for calculating this

Comment: Yes, excel handles basic arithmetic well.
What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show an example of what you want together with what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Kevin here is an excert from my spreadsheet. The 0's and 1's in the GIR line are the correct results but have no formulas in these cells. I would like excel to be able to calculate these results with a formula.

Comment: Hole                 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Par of hole 4 3 4 4 5 4 4 3 4
Hole Index 7 3 10 4 15 8 5 12 6
Score (R)         4 3 6 4 6 5 4 3 6
Putts         1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2
GIR (H)         1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
notes: I play off a handicap of 13, so I receive a shot on all holes except the 5th where I don’t receive a shot.                                                                  I would need to be on the green for 3 on the par 5, 5th hole for it to be a green in regulation as I don’t get a stroke on this hole.

Comment: i.e On hole 1, I receive a shot, my score of 4 less my 1 putt = 3strokes is a GIR, so would be 1.                                                                              On hole 2, I receive a shot, my score of 3 less my 2 putts = 1stroke, so would be a GIR, and would be a 1.                                                               On hole 3, I receive a shot, my score of 6 less my 2 putts = 4strokes ( SAME AS THE PAR OF THE HOLE), so would NOT be a GIR and would be 0.

Comment: On hole 5, I do not receive a shot, my score of 6 less my 2 putts = 4 strokes, so would NOT be a GIR and would be 0.

Comment: Hi Murray, "please edit your question" also please format your data, currently your comment might as well be øo<dusvfilzfdhliufh<lisduilfuhSLDHUF as it is completely unreadable. You can add pictures or format your data into a table.

Comment: Sorry about this Kevin, how do I add an attachment or put a table into my comments to show you what I mean?

Comment: Hi kevin, I think I entered a image into  'enter image description" above. If you click on it the image should appear

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure I understand your full question but I will give you an answer which answers what I think you need.

[image: Example Table]

Given the above example, the formula in Cell `C5` is `=IF((C2-C3)<C1;1;0)`
This subtracts the number of puts you have from your total score for the hole, if it is less than the par of the hole then you should have reached the GIR and the result will be `1`. If the puts minus your score is higher than the par of the hole then you did not reach GIR and you get a 0 here.

If you want to add a condition where you only get GIR if you did actually hit the Green in Regulation AND you scored points for that hole (not a requirement for GIR, you can hit the green off the tee on a par 4 and score GIR but still need 8 putts and hence not score any points for the hole, but...) then, assuming your handicapped score is in Cell `C4`, change the formula too `=IF((C2-C3)<C1;IF(C4>0;1;0))`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Kevin,I have looked at your suggestions and have got it to work. Your first formula i.e=IF((C2-C3)<C1;1,0) works well for those holes where I get a handicap stroke on this hole. Note:between 1 and 0 is a comma not a semi colon.                                                                      For the holes that I dont get a handicap stroke according to the course index rating I have used the same formula but added a -1 in the formula to read =IF((C2-C3)<(C1-1);1,0) and it will enter the correct GIR depending how many strokes and putts I have for the hole. So,it works, thanks for help

Comment: No problem, please mark this answer as an answer so the question is removed from the unanswered questions list. Also note that a semi-colon or comma is a regional restriction within Excel. In Norway (where I live) I have to use a semi-colon despite having the system language in English.